# Create ID for specific sequence of consecutive days based on grouping variable in R

Tags: r, lubridate

For a list of events at the country-day level, we would like to create a unique ID for a sequence of consecutive days in a specific country (if two or more days of events in a country are consecutive --> create unique ID), so that I can ultimately reduce the data frame to specific sequences of events rather than event days.

I did not manage to aggregate the data based on the sequence of events. I believe this response is similar ([Creating groups of consecutive days meeting a given criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274990/creating-groups-of-consecutive-days-meeting-a-given-criteria)) however it is in SQL.

The data has the following format:

```
country <- c("Angola","Angola","Angola","Angola","Angola", "Benin","Benin","Benin","Benin","Benin","Benin")
event_date <- as.Date(c("2017-06-16", "2017-06-17", "2017-06-18", "2017-08-22", "2017-08-23", "2019-04-18", "2019-04-19", "2019-04-20", "2018-03-15", "2018-03-16", "2016-03-17"))

mydata <- data.frame(country, event_date)
```

In the output, I expect to have a new column with the ID that is unique to each series of events in a country:

`seq.ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)`

`mydata2 <- data.frame(country, event_date, seq.ID)`

So that ultimately, I can reduce the data to the level of country and sequence of events:

`mydata3 <- mydata2[!duplicated(mydata2$seq.ID),]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  distinct(seq.ID = cumsum(event_date != lag(event_date, default = first(event_date)) + 1L)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   country [2]
  seq.ID country
   <int> <fct>  
1      1 Angola 
2      2 Angola 
3      1 Benin  
4      2 Benin  
5      3 Benin
```

You can also use the `.keep_all` argument in `distinct` and preserve the first date of each sequence:

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  distinct(seq.ID = cumsum(event_date != lag(event_date, default = first(event_date)) + 1L),
           .keep_all = TRUE)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   country [2]
  country event_date seq.ID
  <fct>   <date>      <int>
1 Angola  2017-06-16      1
2 Angola  2017-08-22      2
3 Benin   2019-04-18      1
4 Benin   2018-03-15      2
5 Benin   2016-03-17      3
```

In case of desired non-aggregated output with different sequence IDs, you could do:

```
mydata %>%
  mutate(
    seq.ID = cumsum(
      (event_date != lag(event_date, default = first(event_date)) + 1L) |
        country != lag(country, default = first(country))
    )
  )

   country event_date seq.ID
1   Angola 2017-06-16      1
2   Angola 2017-06-17      1
3   Angola 2017-06-18      1
4   Angola 2017-08-22      2
5   Angola 2017-08-23      2
6    Benin 2019-04-18      3
7    Benin 2019-04-19      3
8    Benin 2019-04-20      3
9    Benin 2018-03-15      4
10   Benin 2018-03-16      4
11   Benin 2016-03-17      5
```

Note that there is a typo in your last `event_date`, this is why the outputs don't correspond 100% to your desired output.

Comment: Thank you very much....I just realized that I missed to provide a crucial line in the code (what the seq ID should look like) - and just edited it. The tricky bit is that I would like every unique country-sequence to have their own ID (i.e. they shouldn't be repetitive across countries). So that ultimately I can select all unique country-sequences easily by deleting duplicates.

Comment: See my edit - note that there is a typo in your last `event_date` so the last line doesn't correspond to your desired output.

Comment: Thanks much for this solution. While it works well for the sample I provided, it doesn't work on the full dataset with the exact same data structure. I still try to figure out what the problem is and let you know once I find a solution.

Comment: Just figured out that I had to add arrange(country, event_date) to make it work properly with the full dataset.